# Why w3wp (IIS7) is not reset after modifying web.config

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

In IIS7, why w3wp is not reset after web.config is amended? I observed the memoory remains the same.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you modify web.config it's the AppDomain hosted in the `w3wp` process which is unloaded. This doesn't mean that the memory should change. Also there's the auto start feature in IIS 7.5 and ASP.NET 4.0 which could load it once again to avoid cold starts.